# User Independant Share Folder for different user

Tags: command-line, 22.04, samba, users, shared-folders

I have a samba related question if anyone can help. I have set up samba on the Ubuntu server. I want to configure samba to allow access to my external HDD. I made 2 users, one is me who can access all folders inside that HDD and the other is my sister whom I want give access to just the movies folder. Please can someone guide me how do I setup?